# Stata. Sorting data

Tags: sorting, stata

So I have a dummy variable and I would like to bring up all the first names and last names who have a value 1 of the dummy variable. Say the dummy is called `var`. I want to bring up a list of the first names and last names who have `var=1`.

Anyone know how I could do that?

I tried

```
display "`firstname' `lastname'" if var==1
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: There is no way to answer this without knowledge of the specific programming language you are working in and more background for your problem.

Comment: @Slater Tyranus The tag `Stata` does specify language.

Comment: Your problem is solved, but for future questions please note that "didn't work" is a lousy error report: spell out what happened and why it's not what you want.

Comment: why do questions get downvoted? did I do something wrong?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but maybe because your question is very basic some users sensed that no research effort was put into the problem. Also, "didn't work" is not an informative message of why your code is failing and the formatting of the post was not good. You title your question "Stata. Sorting data" but `sort`ing is a well defined concept in Stata (run `help sort`). "Listing", of course is accurate for your problem, but "Displaying data" is more consistent with the code you gave. Take a look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist.

Comment: And read also http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down.

Comment: is there a better place to go for people who are new to programming? I thought this site was simply a place to ask questions about how to program.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. This question isn't about programming in any strong sense, but a learner Stata question. Statalist is more receptive of general Stata questions, but they also expect you to work at the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `list` with the `if` qualifier.

```
sysuse auto, clear
list make if (rep78 == 1)
```

`display` is for strings and scalars. I suspect your code returns your first `firstname`.

Comment: excellent. Didn't know there was a list command. Basically all I needed was
list firstname lastname if var==1